# Translate "by" in German

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb

In English, we can use "by, with, via, through" in many situations interchangeably. In general all mean to use something.

In German, can we use them interchangeably? I mean for example "durch, via, bei, von"

- lernen bei/durch/via Lehrer
- fahren bei Bus
- stören jmdn. via Musik

And etc.

Comment: I'm afraid your assumption is wrong. They're interchangeable *neither* in English *nor* in German.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Yes, going *by* bus is quite different from going *through* the bus.

Comment: Can you translate *so* in Englisch?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. You can't interchange the words "by, with, via, through" in English

> The mailbox is <del>*with*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **by** the bus stop.
> Be back <del>*with*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **by** ten o'clock!.
> Hamlet was written <del>*with*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **by** William Shakespeare.

> He went <del>*by*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **with** his friends.
> She cuts the rope <del>*by*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **with** a knife.
> He spoke <del>*by*</del> <del>*via*</del> <del>*through*</del> **with** sadness in his voice.

And also in German you can't freely interchange *"durch, via, bei, von"* because they have different meanings (like their English counterparts)

> Lisa lernt **bei** Professor Steiner.

The original meaning of this sentence is this: Lisa is located next to Professor Steiner (maybe in the same room) and there she is learning. In a figurative sense this means, the professor is teaching her (maybe even via distance learning, i.e. without really being next to each other). This sentence does not include the meaning, that professor Steiner is helpful for Lisa. This meaning also isn't excluded. The sentence just doesn't tell anything about helpfulness.

> Lisa lernt **durch** Professor Steiner.

This sentence doesn't say anything about location or distances. It says, that the professor helps Lisa to learn. The professor is actively doing something to teach Lisa.

> Lisa lernt **von** Professor Steiner.

Again there is no information about location or distances in this sentences. It means, that the professor does or did something that allows Lisa to learn. But it is not necessary that the professor is aware of Lisa learning. Today, in 21<sup>st</sup> century it is still possible to learn ***von*** Mozart, Shakespeare or Michelangelo although they are all dead for many centuries. But you can't learn ***durch*** them because the are not able to activity do anything now.

> <del>*Lisa lernt **via** Professor Steiner.*</del>

This simply is wrong and makes no sense at all.

---

> Hans fährt **mit** dem Bus.

Hans is traveling from one place to another and he takes the bus for his journey.

> Hans fährt **bei** dem Bus.

Hans is driving his own car or he is riding a bike or uses any other vehicle but the bus. Hans is not in the Bus. He is driving in another vehicle side by side to the bus.

> Hans fährt **durch** den Bus.

Hans is driving in his own vehicle and he crashes into the bus so hard, that he traverses through the whole bus. So, in his car, he hits a hole into the bus on one side, moves through the bus and leaves the bus on the other side, still in his own vehicle. (also note, that here we use accusative case, but the other prepositions needed dative case)

> <del>*Hans fährt **von** dem Bus.*</del>
> <del>*Hans fährt **via** dem Bus.*</del>

Both sentences are wrong and don't mean anything.

> Hans fährt **via** Bus von Paris nach Berlin.

Note the missing article between *via* and *Bus!* This sentence means the same as *»Hans fährt **mit dem** Bus von Paris nach Berlin«* but when you use *via,* you have to say from where to where you are traveling. The sentence *»Hans fährt **via** Bus«* doesn't make much sense. Better use *mit* (and an article) instead.

---

> Leon stört seine Eltern **mit** seiner Musik.

Leon disturbs and annoys his parents with his music. He is playing music but his parents don't like it.

> Leon stört seine Eltern **durch** seine Musik.

This sentence means the same as the previous one. (Note, that *mit* needed *seine Musik* to be in dative case, while *durch* needs accusative case.)

> <del>*Leon stört seine Eltern **via** seine Musik.*</del>

You can say it this way, but this is not recommended. This sentence means the same as the two previous sentences, but it still is a bad choice. Native speakers normally don't use *via* in such a sentence. It sounds aloof and strange.

> <del>*Leon stört seine Eltern **bei** seine Musik.*</del>
> <del>*Leon stört seine Eltern **von** seine Musik.*</del>

Wrong. No meaning.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at "by" and "bei" as [false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend).

Comment: small mistake: Hans crashes *into* the bus. Hans cannot crash the bus unless he's driving the bus.

Comment: Or, the bus could be [*this*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/InnoTrans_2016_%E2%80%93_Chinese_Bus%E2%80%A6_-ish_Thing_%2829861803605%29.jpg) bus

Comment: I was thinking about using a skateboard or scooter to drive through the bus (from front to back), without any crashing :-)

Comment: Got nothing else to do all day long, do you... (upvoted) ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr schölnast. The answer was very helpful. How can i find the right " using somthing" word for any verb in germany? Sometime i could find in duden but sometimes not not in duden or pons

Comment: @omidrezanouri: Learning how to use prepositions correctly is one of the hardest parts of learning a new language because they are used so often but differ so much from language to language. I think the best way is to use the language you are learning as often as possible. Watch movies in German language, read German books, chat with native speakers in their language.

Comment: @omidrezanouri adverbs are essentially multi-meaning words (just like "Schloss" can mean "castle" or "lock"), and the intended meaning depends on context - typically the verb the adverb goes with (some combinations are even idioms that you have to learn individually, just like a "red herring" is neither red nor a fish). Films are a rich source of idioms, as are written texts. Another excellent resource for English<->German is https://dict.cc, which typically lists many verb-adverb combinations.

Comment: Of course you can say "via Bus", "via Bahn", etc. "Er reist via Bus/Bahn an", ie. you dont need to specify places. Also, you can use via when talking about a route stopover "Er fährt via Hamburg nach Berlin".

Answer (score 1):

No, these words cannot be used interchangeably! Your example with *bei* is wrong, one would say *... mit dem Bus fahren*.